# Custom widget does not fill available space in width

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a custom widget for TextView. The created custom component works fine when declared through xml. But when I try to add it to layout dynamically through code , it does not fill the available width.

Can any one help me how  to make it occupy full width.

My xml layout is as below :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout 
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/llayout"
 >
```

In Activity file , I try to add a custom widget to linear layout as below :

```
String yourText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
                    "Ut volutpat interdum interdum. Nulla laoreet lacus diam, vitae " +
                    "sodales sapien commodo faucibus. Vestibulum et feugiat enim. Donec " +
                    "semper mi et euismod tempor. Sed sodales eleifend mi id varius. Nam " +
                    "et ornare enim, sit amet gravida sapien. Quisque gravida et enim vel " +
                    "volutpat. Vivamus egestas ut felis a blandit. Vivamus fringilla " +
                    "dignissim mollis. Maecenas imperdiet interdum hendrerit. Aliquam" +
                    " dictum hendrerit ultrices. Ut vitae vestibulum dolor. Donec auctor ante" +
                    " eget libero molestie porta. Nam tempor fringilla ultricies. Nam sem " +
                    "lectus, feugiat eget ullamcorper vitae, ornare et sem. Fusce dapibus ipsum" +
                    " sed laoreet suscipit. ";
         LinearLayout llayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llayout);
         ExpandableTextView expandableTextView = new ExpandableTextView(getApplicationContext());
         LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         expandableTextView.setLayoutParams(lpView);
         expandableTextView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
         expandableTextView.setTextSize(25);
         expandableTextView.setText(yourText);
         llayout.addView(expandableTextView);
```

## ExpandableTextView

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.andr.expandabletextviewwidget;



import com.andr.kamal56.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


     public class ExpandableTextView extends TextView{

    private static final int DEFAULT_TRIM_LENGTH = 200;
    private static final String ELLIPSIS = ".....";

    private CharSequence originalText;
    private CharSequence trimmedText;
    private BufferType bufferType;
    private boolean trim = true;
    private int trimLength;

    public ExpandableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableTextView);
        this.trimLength = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_trimLength, DEFAULT_TRIM_LENGTH);
        typedArray.recycle();

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trim = !trim;
                setText();
                requestFocusFromTouch();                
            }
        });
    }

     private void setText() {
            super.setText(getDisplayableText(), bufferType);
        }

    private CharSequence getDisplayableText() {
        return trim ? trimmedText : originalText;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        originalText = text;
        trimmedText = getTrimmedText(text);
        bufferType = type;
        setText();

    }



     private CharSequence getTrimmedText(CharSequence text) {
            if (originalText != null && originalText.length() > trimLength) {
                return new SpannableStringBuilder(originalText, 0, trimLength + 1).append(ELLIPSIS);
            } else {
                return originalText;
            }
        }


     public CharSequence getOriginalText() {
            return originalText;
        }

        public void setTrimLength(int trimLength) {
            this.trimLength = trimLength;
            trimmedText = getTrimmedText(originalText);
            setText();
        }

        public int getTrimLength() {
            return trimLength;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is in `ExpandableTextView`? Have you made changes to `onMeasure()` that would affect this?

Comment: updated with ExpandableTextView class

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in your activity code. There are many different `LayoutParams` classes and sometimes you can end up using the wrong one by mistake because the wrong one is being imported.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I imported the same and also made change the way you mentioned, but still it does n't expand its width

Comment: @Android_programmer_office At this point I suggest you use HierarchyViewer to inspect the layout in real time and look for anything strange. This tool comes with the Android SDK. You may have to use an emulator as it doesn't always work with real devices.